# How to model transitive dependencies between static libraries in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Given an executable `myExe`, and 2 static libraries `myLib1` and `myLib2`. Given the following dependencies `myExe -> myLib1 -> myLib2`, how should you model transitive dependency between `myLib2` and `myLib1`?

It seems that the correct way to do it may be:

```
target_link_libraries(myLib2 myLib1)
```

But, according to the documentation:

> Specify libraries or flags to use when **linking** a given target and/or its dependents

Also, `add_dependencies` does not seem to be transitive.

So I find this confusing to use `target_link_libraries` and I am wondering if there is another "cleaner" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For express **usage** dependency `myLib1 -> myLib2` (that is, library `myLib1` *uses* functions defined in `myLib2`), use

```
target_link_libraries(myLib2 myLib1)
```

While `target_link_libraries` doesn't affect on the *file* `myLib2.a` (because static libraries are never linked), an effect will be seen when `myLib2` will be linked into shared library or executable:

```
target_link_libraries(myExe myLib2)
```

will automatically link `myExe` with `myLib1`.

---

Note again, that such linkage propagation for static libraries works only when `myLib2` is used in the **same project** which calls `target_link_libraries(myLib2 myLib1)`.

Attempt to `target_link_libraries(myExe myLib2)` from *another* project will link just with `myLib2.a` file, which doesn't contain information about `myLib2`.

Comment: Is there a way to limit visibility from myExe to myLib1. (I'd like to prevent teammates from accidentally using the transitive library in the target library)

Comment: It depends on your understanding of "visibility", but you may try to use `PRIVATE` linkage: `target_link_libraries(myLib2 PRIVATE myLib1)`.

Comment: I mean not being able to include or reference myLib1 in any way (from the target). I already tried your suggestion but didn't work unfortunately (the target is missing header files)

Comment: "the target is missing header files" - Do you mean that you have an error about absent of a `myLib1` header file when compiler the executable? In that case you executable already uses `myLib1`. Or `myLib2` interface includes `myLib1`. BTW, you may prepare separate question post and describe your problem in more details.